# Start vncserver on :0 instead of :1

Tags: linux, vnc, xserver, vnc-server

Is it possible to start vncserver on `:0` when its already started on `:1` without having to reboot the system?

System details:
Gnome desktop manager

```
[root@server ~]# uname -a
Linux server.com 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 15 10:48:38 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

Running on `:1`

```
[root@server ~]# vncserver :1
A VNC server is already running as :1
```

Want to use `:0` instead but getting the following error:

```
[root@server ~]# vncserver :0

WARNING: The first attempt to start Xvnc failed, possibly because the font
catalog is not properly configured.  Attempting to determine an appropriate
font path for this system and restart Xvnc using that font path ...
Could not start Xvnc.

_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running

Fatal server error:
Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running

Fatal server error:
Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running
```

List of files under `/tmp`

```
[root@server ~]# ls /tmp/.
./         ../        .esd-0/    .esd-500/  .ICE-unix/ .X11-unix/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

vncserver tries to create a full window manager and all that, and your :0 likely already has those things going for it.

What you are looking for is using "x11vnc." I believe it will give you the desired effect, even without the :0 argument. There is a distinct yum-package, "x11vnc."

Comment: Is there a way to restart `:0`? instead of having to install additional packages

Comment: It sounds like you want to not run X (or gdm) in the first place. In that case, you might disable it using chkconfig or prevent the system from entering run-level "5."
See also:http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-uninstall-gdm-centos-fedora-redhat-linux/
I suggest Method #2, because you still might need some of those components of gnome, for your vncserver on :0 or :1.

Comment: setting run level to `3` did the trick, was able to start `vncserver :0` then .. Is there any perf issues associated with lowering to this level?

Comment: I don't think so. chkconfig will outline what programs are run on what run-level. Consult that and make sure you have the right services running at the right time. Depending on your distro, you might need to look other places for the list - it's out of my expertise area - I've never run a run-level 3 by default.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is stated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122067/make-sure-x-server-isnt-already-running). You have to first find `Xorg` processes with `ps aux | grep Xorg` and then kill them.

Answer (score -1):

Simply terminate all VNCs processes. You can find the process number by running the following command:

> ps -ef | grep vnc